# Trying to draw a 3D line graph in openGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

I have a 2D sine curve on the x and y axes, and I want to make it 3D. I'm wanting the end result to look something like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/p07a.gif). I think I do this by rotating the curve's vertices around the y-axis and joining them all together somehow.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the distance from the center rather than the x position as the input to the sine function. Something like this:

```
z = sin (sqrt ((x * x) + (y * y)));
```

You can then march across the x and y axes, plug in the values, and draw lines between the values, like this:

```
glBegin (GL_LINES);
for (x = xmin; x <= xmax; x++)
{
    for (y = ymin; y <= ymax; y++)
    {
        z = sin (sqrt ((x*x) + (y*y)));
        glVertex3f (x, y, z);
    }
}
glEnd ();
```

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGL Programming book on Wikibooks has a [scientific arc](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming#The_scientific_arc) that shows how to plot functions in both 2D and 3D using modern OpenGL. It sounds like [the fourth part](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Scientific_OpenGL_Tutorial_04) might be what you're interested in.

Basically, the function you want to plot is evaluated in NxN points and the results saved to a texture, which is then used as the Z-coordinate in the vertex shader.